Spring JPA Single Table inheritance clause order in query
Spring Data Jpa allows for inheritance with multiple strategies, one of them being Single table, in which a discriminator column is used to differentiate among various child classes.
Suppose we have
@Entity
@Table("table")
@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator_type")
class Parent {/*definition of PK and other fields*/}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CHILD")
class Child extends Parent {}

Now, if one creates a JpaRepository<Child, Long> and runs a simple findById(), the generated query will look something like
select * from table where discriminator_type = 'CHILD' and id = ?1;

This is, for obvious performance reasons, not efficient (the id should go first - in this situation, the type is even redundant).
Is there any way in which the type clause can be moved on the last place in the query?

for obvious performance reasons, not efficient - can't believe that such databases to exist.

@AndreyB.Panfilov you mean DBs that are efficient?

what I did mean is the following: the all DBs which plays for either premier or first league (oracle, mssql, postgres, mysql) do not suffer from the order of where predicates
